# How do I compare letters in Greek?

Tags: swift, string, xcode

I'm trying to write a word game in Greek. I have the project working in English and French, but I'm getting anomalous results in Greek.

The UI looks like the image below:

[image]

In this image, all of the letters except the "Σ" are accepted. The sigma is rejected and I don't know why.

I use two files, a Greek letter file and a Greek word file:

greekLetters.json

```
...
{
    "uppercase": "Ρ",
    "language": "Greek",
    "position": 17
},
{
    "uppercase": "‬Σ",
    "language": "Greek",
    "position": 18
},
{
    "uppercase": "Τ",
    "language": "Greek",
    "position": 19
},
...
```

greekWords.json:

```
...
{  
  "number": 462,
  "name": "κρατήστε",
  "translation": "hold",
  "language": "Greek"
},
```

I load these files into a Core Data model. The data looks like this:

[image]

My code to grab a random word is:

```
  let tempWord = words.randomElement()!
        currentWord = tempWord.name?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).uppercased() ?? "No Word"
```

I compare the random word with the game letters like this:

```
let letterObject = letters[indexPath.row]
        let tempLetter: String = letterObject.uppercase ?? "No letter found"
        let letter = tempLetter.stripingDiacritics
       
if currentWord.folding(options: .diacriticInsensitive, locale: .none).contains(letter) {
            correctLetters.append(letter)
            letterCell?.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            letterCollection.cellForItem(at: indexPath)?.backgroundColor = correctButtonColor
            
            
            manageCorrectLetter()
        }
        else {
            letterCell?.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

            letterCollection.cellForItem(at: indexPath)?.backgroundColor = incorrectButtonColor
            
            manageIncorrectLetter()
        }
```

Finally, I'm using sigma as an example, this is occurring with several other letters as well.

Comment: Is it being considered as a command or function?

Comment: Thanks for answering, I don't understand your question. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: It seems that the string "‬Σ" in your JSON file contains additional (invisible) Unicode characters. I suggest to delete the string and add it again. Then everything should work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to answers and comments from other questions, I have a solution that appears to work ok:

```
  let letterObject = letters[indexPath.row]
  var tempLetter: String = letterObject.uppercase ?? "No letter found"
        
  tempLetter.unicodeScalars.removeAll(where: { !CharacterSet.alphanumerics.contains($0) })
        
  let letter = tempLetter.stripingDiacritics
```

Comment: That is not the proper fix IMO. You should remove the invisible characters from the JSON file instead. Btw, the problem is unrelated to Greek characters.

Comment: Hmm. I changed the letters as you suggested, but from Wikipedia. How can I see/remove the invisible characters. Is there a better source?I agree that this is not a greek issue. I'm having the same problem now in Hebrew and Arabic.